# passing arguments to a function in javascript but function not working

Tags: javascript, css, function, arguments, onload

I have some javascript code which detects whether the useragent is an android, iphone or ipod and then only loads my javascript files if this is the case.
The following code works perfectly but I am aware that I do not need to have two 'createscript' functions (with different names) that do the same thing so I am trying to use a parameter/variable instead. I've tried everything i can think of but it's not working.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
     navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
     navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
     navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {
        function addLoadEvent(func) {
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
                window.onload = func;
            } else {
             window.onload = function() {
                if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
                }
                func();
                }
        }
        }


function createScript() 
{ 
var oNode=document.createElement("script"); 
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(oNode);

oNode.setAttribute("id", "newScript", 0); 
oNode.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript", 0); 
oNode.setAttribute("src", "nav.js", 0); 
} 


function createScript_() 
{ 
var oNode=document.createElement("script"); 
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(oNode);

oNode.setAttribute("id", "newScript", 0); 
oNode.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript", 0); 
oNode.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js", 0); 
}

addLoadEvent(createScript);
addLoadEvent(createScript_);
}
</script>
```

And here is the new code with parameters that I have been trying out (its the same as above accept I've set a parameter for the createscript function) But it doesnt work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
 navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
 navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
 navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {
alert("This is a mobile device");
    function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
         window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
            oldonload();
            }
            func();
            }
    }
    }


function createScript(scriptname) 
{ 
var oNode=document.createElement("script"); 
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(oNode);

oNode.setAttribute("id", "newScript", 0); 
oNode.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript", 0); 
oNode.setAttribute("src", + scriptname + , 0); 
} 

createscriptlibrary = createScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js");
createmyscript = createScript("nav.js");

addLoadEvent(createscriptlibrary);
addLoadEvent(createmyscript);
}
</script>
```

It's probably something small but I can't figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Edit:
Thanks to @t-j-crowder I have edited my code as follows and this works perfect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
 navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
 navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
 navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {

    function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
         window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
            oldonload();
            }
            func();
            }
    }
    }
function createscript(scriptName) {
    var oNode = document.createElement('script');
    oNode.src = scriptName;
    document.body.appendChild(oNode);
}

addLoadEvent(createscript.bind(undefined, "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"));
addLoadEvent(createscript.bind(undefined, "nav.js"));
}
</script>
```

There are still some issues with this code as @t-j-crowder pointed out about the fact that I cannot rely on my two .js files loading in the right order so I will try out the guard as he suggested below in his answer. Thanks for all the comments.

New edit to question-loading in a css file:
I now have the following code which loads my jquery lib and nav2.js file when the page is loaded. This works perfect. I am trying to get my code to load a css file dynamically when the browser supports javascript but it is not working. Can anybody see why? is it because the page is displaying before the css file is loaded? Here is my script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadcssfile(filename){
  var fileref=document.createElement("link");
  fileref.href = filename;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}
    function addLoadEvent(func) {
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
                window.onload = func;
        } else {
            window.onload = function() {
                    if (oldonload) {
                        oldonload();
                    }
                func();
                }
        }
    }

function createscript(scriptName) {
    var oNode = document.createElement('script');
    oNode.src = scriptName;
    document.body.appendChild(oNode);
}


addLoadEvent(createscript.bind(undefined, "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"));
addLoadEvent(createscript.bind(undefined, "nav2.js"));
loadcssfile("jqueryjava.css");

</script>
```

Comment: Wow, a lot of code to determine if window.onload was set already...

Comment: Not tested but I think `("src", scriptname , 0)` instead of this `("src", + scriptname + , 0)` will do.

Comment: @Harry Thank you for this but I had actually tried that out before adding the + in and it didn't work. Thanks for pointing out the error.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that doesn't work is that `createScript` doesn't return a function, but you're expecting it to.

The simplest way is just to do this:

```
addLoadEvent(function() { createscript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"); });
addLoadEvent(function() { createScript("nav.js"); });
```

Note, though, that you're giving the same `id` value to each `script` tag created by `createScript`, which isn't valid.

In an ES5-enabled environment, you could use `Function#bind`, but something about your question suggests to me you can't rely on being in an ES5-enabled environment. But for completeness:

```
addLoadEvent(createscript.bind(undefined, "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"));
addLoadEvent(createScript.bind(undefined, "nav.js"));
```

---

Actually, no, the *simplest* way is to use any of several libraries designed for this, like RequireJS. :-)

---

Side note: Your `createScript` function can be markedly simpler (and in fact, the one you've quoted in your question has a syntax error as of the `+` before `scriptName`):

```
function createScript(scriptName) {
    var oNode = document.createElement('script');
    oNode.src = scriptName;
    document.body.appendChild(oNode);
}
```

There's no need to set `type`, and you don't want to set `id` unless you're also passing in an `id` for each script. And both `src` and `type` are reflected properties, no need to use `setAttribute` on them.

---

And a final side note: Your `nav.js` **cannot** rely on jQuery already being loaded if you load the scripts this way. `nav.js` can be retrieved and evaluated (run) before jQuery is, even though you're creating the jQuery script element first. Scripts added dynamically are not necessarily evaluated in order. So you need a guard on your `nav.js` code, like:

```
(function() {
    check();

    function check() {
        if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
            setTimeout(check, 50);
        }
        else {
            init();
        }
    }

    function init() {
    }
})();
```

That will check for jQuery and wait 50ms if it doesn't find it (and keep doing that forever, you might want a master timeout).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will get back to you shortly :)

Comment: I have edited my post above as you can see. I have tried out your code and it works perfect, thank you. Thanks for informing me about the fact that the scripts are not necessarily evaluated in order. I have not tried out your guard yet. I was reading on the RequireJS page you suggested and it seems they have a  way of specifying file dependencies too so i might try this out. To be honest I'm not quite sure what an ES5-enabled environment is. I need to look into this further.At the moment this code works on my iPhone and also (without the phone detection if)works on my desktop :)

Answer (score 0):

In my latest edit above I was wondering how to add a css file dynamically. 
I have used the following code instead and it is now working. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
var cssNode = document.createElement('link');
cssNode.type = 'text/css';
cssNode.rel = 'stylesheet';
cssNode.href = 'jqueryjava.css';
headID.appendChild(cssNode);
</script>
```